# Using one twisted pair of ethernet cable as control signal

Tags: spi, ethernet, shift-register, rs422

I am designing a system based on [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt441/slyt441.pdf) application note of TI. The overall design goal is to have multiple shift registers, connected via RS-422 and ethernet cables over fairly long distances(up to 5 meters between each node).
Each node should convert the differential RS-422 signal to SPI for the shift register and after that back to differential the RS-422 for daisy-chaining nodes.
Each node can have a single power supply or - if spatial possible - share a power bus with neighbouring nodes.

My plan is to have MOSI,MISO and CLK as differential signals in a twisted pair, since they will have the highest data rate(not specified yet). Using standard ethernet cables this setup will use 3 of 4 twisted pairs. This leaves me with one twisted pair.

For clean initial conditions I would like to have STROBE/LATCH and OUTPUT_ENABLE for clean operations as control signals.
Is there any problem using the remaining twisted pair non-differential for the control signals?

Comment: You'll have 5m of the two signals tightly twisted together, so crosstalk will be severe unless the edge rate of the signals is very low.

Comment: What's providing the ground reference among the nodes? This would also be carrying the return current for any single-ended signals.

Comment: Dave: Thats a good call! Thanks - haven't thought of that. In this scenario the ground reference would be provided by the different power supplies or the shared power bus, which would create a hell of a ground loop - not good. I guess I need to have one ground wire in the ethernet cable and do some circuit magic at each node for my control signals

Comment: SPI may not work effectively when slave responds to master due to accumulated delays.

Comment: For 5m distance if everything is well done, you could push max. 25Mbit/s. Not to mention the complexity and cost of such circuit. It would be economically better to use a separate MCU for each node and some standard communication like CAN, RS485,...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. In my use case even 1kBit/s will be more than enough. Furthermore the slaves response is only needed once -or most at any system startup once a day- for scanning connected loads. Its a very dumb automation system for driving loads from a central controller - no hard timing constraints or speed requierements.
Since I want to drive up to 16 loads on each node, some kind of multiplexing is needed, so I've chosen shift registers. Also shift registers provide a possibility for daisychaining nodes. I dont see the benefits of a complicated microcontroller, arbitation etc

Comment: perhaps use  clock silence (a missing pulse detector)  to trigger strobe/latch.  why do you need OE?  shielded ethernet cable gets you an extra conductor.